# MySQL80 service starts and stops automatically on Windows: How to troubleshoot?

Tags: mysql

I'm encountering an issue with the MySQL80 service on my Windows machine. The service starts but then stops automatically shortly after, displaying an error message indicating that it stops if not in use.

I've attempted the following troubleshooting steps without success:

- Verified the service configuration in Windows Services, which shows that the MySQL80 service starts and then stops.
- Checked the MySQL error log for any specific error messages, but it doesn't provide clear information on why the service is stopping.
- Ensured that no other service or application is using the same port as the MySQL server (default is 3306).
- Reviewed the MySQL configuration file (my.ini) to ensure settings are correct.
- Verified the Windows Firewall and antivirus settings to ensure they are not blocking MySQL traffic.
- Checked the permissions on the MySQL data directory to ensure the service has appropriate access.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists, and I'm unable to keep the MySQL service running.

I'm seeking guidance on further steps to troubleshoot this problem. What are additional troubleshooting steps or considerations I might be overlooking to resolve this issue and keep the MySQL service running without interruptions?

Any insights or guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Error message :

Attempting to start service MySQL80....................

A task may only be disposed if it is in a completion state (RanToCompletion, Faulted or Canceled).

Comment: Rename the error log file then try to start the service again. You should get a new error log file, take a look inside it and if there are just a few lines, copy and paste them into your question. If there are so many lines from the error log file, try identifying the last few lines where it might contain the detail why the server is not starting. If you post the content of `my.ini` here, it might help as well.